# Codeigniter form validation returns all errors if file is too big

Tags: forms, codeigniter, validation

I have a controller method that checks for post data and parses this through form_validation run method. There is also an image upload field in my view where an image can be uploaded. 
The problem is that when a file gets uploaded which is way too big, let's say over 10MB, the form validation will return every single error defined in my validation rules.
If i upload a file which is still too big, but not too much, i will get the correct error message back.

My code looks like this:

```
public function addVacancy()
{
    $this->is_logged_in();

    //Check if user has correct permission to access this page
    $aclConfig = array('userID' => $this->auth_user_id);
    $this->load->library('acl', $aclConfig);
    $redirect_protocol = USE_SSL ? 'https' : NULL;

    if (!empty($this->auth_user_id)) {
        if ( $this->acl->hasPermission("create_vacancy") ) {
            //If the value is filled in we know it is an admin creating a vacancy for an organisation, we also set a boolean so we show a bit different message in confirmation.php
            $orgId = $this->input->post('orgid');
            if (empty($orgId)) {
                $orgId = $this->userRoles_model->getOrgUserId($this->auth_user_id);
            } else {
                $adminEditing = TRUE;
            }
            $vacancyId = null;
            $data = null;

            if (strlen($this->input->post('occupancy')) != 1) {
                $occupancy = 3;
            } else {
                $occupancy = $this->input->post('occupancy');
            }

            $vacancy_data = [
                'org_id' => $orgId,
                'offer' => $this->input->post('offer'),
                'name' => $this->input->post('title'),
                'website' => $this->input->post('website'),
                'description' => $this->input->post('vacdescription'),
                'address_line_1' => $this->input->post('route'),
                'address_line_2' => $this->input->post('street_number'),
                'address_postal_code' => $this->input->post('postalcode'),
                'address_city' => $this->input->post('city'),
                'address_country' => $this->input->post('country'),
                'number_required' => $this->input->post('count'),
                'engagement' => $this->input->post('time'),
                'occupancy_kind' => $occupancy,
                'create_time' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                'accessibility' => $this->input->post('vacaccessibility'),
                'status' => 0
            ];

            $dates_data = [
                'fullvacancydate' => $this->input->post('daterange-vacancy')
            ];

            if (!empty($dates_data['fullvacancydate'])) {
                $splitfromandto = explode(" - ", $dates_data['fullvacancydate']);
                $vacancy_data['vacancy_start_date'] = date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime($splitfromandto[0]));
                $vacancy_data['vacancy_end_date'] = date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime($splitfromandto[1]));
            } else {
                $today = date('Y-m-d');
                $todayPlus6Months = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+6 months", strtotime($today)));
                $vacancy_data['vacancy_start_date'] = $today;
                $vacancy_data['vacancy_end_date'] = $todayPlus6Months;
            }

            $contactId = $this->input->post('contactpersons');
            if ($contactId == 0) {
                $contact_data = [
                    'org_id' => $orgId,
                    'family_name' => $this->input->post('family_name'),
                    'first_name' => $this->input->post('first_name'),
                    'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                    'phone' => $this->input->post('phone'),
                    'function' => $this->input->post('function')
                ];
            }else{
                $contact_data = (array) $this->orgContacts_model->get($contactId);
            }

            $this->load->library('form_validation');
            $validation_data = array_merge($vacancy_data, $contact_data);
            $this->form_validation->set_data($validation_data);
            $validation_rules = [
                [
                    'field' => 'offer',
                    'label' => 'offer',
                    'rules' => 'trim|required',
                    'errors' => ['required' => 'Wat heb je te bieden is verplicht.']
                ],
                [
                    'field' => 'name',
                    'label' => 'name',
                    'rules' => 'trim|required',
                    'errors' => ['required' => 'Naam is verplicht.']
                ],
                [
                    'field' => 'description',
                    'label' => 'description',
                    'rules' => 'trim|required',
                    'errors' => ['required' => 'Beschrijving is verplicht.']
                ],
                [
                    'field' => 'address_postal_code',
                    'label' => 'address_postal_code',
                    'rules' => 'trim|required',
                    'errors' => ['required' => 'Postcode is verplicht.']
                ],
                [
                    'field' => 'address_city',
                    'label' => 'address_city',
                    'rules' => 'trim|required',
                    'errors' => ['required' => 'Stad of gemeente is verplicht.']
                ],
                [
                    'field' => 'address_country',
                    'label' => 'address_country',
                    'rules' => 'trim|required',
                    'errors' => ['required' => 'Land is verplicht.']
                ],
                [
                    'field' => 'number_required',
                    'label' => 'number_required',
                    'rules' => 'trim|required',
                    'errors' => ['required' => 'Aantal vrijwilligers is verplicht.']
                ],
                [
                    'field' => 'occupancy_kind',
                    'label' => 'occupancy_kind',
                    'rules' => 'trim|required',
                    'errors' => ['required' => 'Bezetting is verplicht.']
                ],
                [
                    'field' => 'family_name',
                    'label' => 'family_name',
                    'rules' => 'trim|required',
                    'errors' => ['required' => 'Familie naam van de contactpersoon is verplicht.']
                ],
                [
                    'field' => 'first_name',
                    'label' => 'first_name',
                    'rules' => 'trim|required',
                    'errors' => ['required' => 'Voornaam van de contactpersoon is verplicht.']
                ],
                [
                    'field' => 'email',
                    'label' => 'email',
                    'rules' => 'trim|required',
                    'errors' => ['required' => 'Email van de contactpersoon is verplicht.']
                ],
                [
                    'field' => 'phone',
                    'label' => 'phone',
                    'rules' => 'trim|required',
                    'errors' => ['required' => 'Telefoonnummer van de contactpersoon is verplicht.']
                ],
                [
                    'field' => 'function',
                    'label' => 'function',
                    'rules' => 'trim|required',
                    'errors' => ['required' => 'Functie van de contactpersoon is verplicht.']
                ],
            ];
            $this->form_validation->set_rules($validation_rules);

            if ($this->form_validation->run()) {

                // Create new contact
                if ($contactId == 0) {
                    $contactId = $this->orgContacts_model->add($contact_data);
                }

                // Create vacancy
                $this->load->model('vacancy/vacancy_model');

                // Var to check
                $check = false;
                $isNoImageChosen = false;

                if(isset($_FILES['userfile']['name']) && is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])) {
                    // Banner Upload
                    $config['upload_path'] = VACANCY_IMAGES;
                    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|PNG|JPG|jpeg|bmp';
                    $config['min_width'] = 1024;
                    $config['min_height'] = 768;
                    $config['max_size'] = 3072;
                    $config['quality'] = 60;

                    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

                    if ($this->upload->do_upload('userfile')) {
                        $uploadData = $this->upload->data();

                        if (isset($uploadData)) {
                            $vacancy_data['banner'] = $uploadData['file_name'];
                            $check = true;
                        }
                    } else {
                        $imageOk = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

                        // Passing Variables
                        $data['title'] = 'Give a Day - Error';
                        $data['class'] = 'vacancy';
                        $data['validationErrors'] = validation_errors();
                        $data['imgErrors'] = $imageOk['error'];

                        $data['feedback'] = array(
                            'type'  => 'alert-danger',
                            'icon'     => 'fa-times',
                            'title' => 'Oops!',
                            'text' => 'Uploaden van de foto is niet gelukt'
                        );

                        $content = 'dashboard/vacancy/error';
                    }
                } else {
                    //check on true cause there is no image selected
                    $check = true;
                    $isNoImageChosen = true;
                }

                //Check if image upload went without errors
                if($check) {
                    //Serialize the accessibility (because more than 1 value can be entered)
                    $vacancy_data['accessibility'] = serialize($vacancy_data['accessibility']);

                    $vacancyId = $this->vacancy_model->add($vacancy_data);

                    // Create Vacancy Contact
                    $vacancyContact['contact_id'] = $contactId;
                    $vacancyContact['vacancy_id'] = $vacancyId;
                    $this->vacancyContacts_model->add($vacancyContact);

                    // Set Interests
                    $this->load->model('vacancy/vacancyInterests_model');
                    $interests = $this->input->post('interests');
                    if ($interests != '') {
                        $interests = explode(",", $interests);
                        foreach ($interests as $id) {
                            $this->vacancyInterests_model->add($vacancyId, $id);
                        }
                    }

                    if ($isNoImageChosen) {
                        $k = array_rand($interests);
                        $randomInterestId = $interests[$k];
                        $randomBannerImageLocation = return_random_interest_banner($randomInterestId);
                        //Because the vacancy has already been created we need to do an update for setting the banner image
                        $bannerData = array (
                            'banner' => $randomBannerImageLocation
                        );
                        $this->vacancies_model->update($vacancyId, $bannerData);
                    }

                    // Set Skills
                    $this->load->model('vacancy/vacancySkills_model');
                    $skills = $this->input->post('skills');
                    if ($skills != '') {
                        $skills = explode(",", $skills);
                        foreach ($skills as $id) {
                            $this->vacancySkills_model->add($vacancyId, $id);
                        }
                    }

                    //Get organisation information for the name
                    $orgdata = $this->organization_model->get($orgId);
                    $orgname = $orgdata->name;
                    $orguserid = $this->userRoles_model->getAdminUserId($orgId);
                    $orguserdata = $this->users_model->get($orguserid[0]->user_id);
                    $orgemail = $orguserdata->email;

                    $mail_data['vacid'] = $vacancyId;
                    $mail_data['vacname'] = $vacancy_data['name'];
                    $mail_data['org_id'] = $orgId;
                    $mail_data['orgname'] = $orgname;
                    $mail_data['contactpersonfirstname'] = $contact_data['first_name'];

                    $this->email->from(GENERAL_MAIL, 'Give a Day');
                    $this->email->to($contact_data['email']);
                    $this->email->cc($orgemail);
                    $this->email->bcc(GENERAL_MAIL);
                    $this->email->subject('Je vrijwilligersactiviteit is aangemaakt');
                    $message = $this->load->view('mail/vacancy/creation_confirmation', $mail_data, TRUE);
                    $this->email->message($message);

                    $this->email->send();

                    // Passing Variables
                    $data['title'] = 'Give a Day - Succes!';
                    $data['class'] = 'vacancy';
                    $data['vacancyId'] = $vacancyId;
                    $data['vacancyName'] = $vacancy_data['name'];
                    if ($adminEditing) {
                        $data['adminedit'] = TRUE;
                        $data['orgid'] = $orgId;
                    }
                    $content = 'dashboard/vacancy/confirmation';
                } else {
                    // Passing Variables
                    $data['title'] = 'Give a Day - Error';
                    $data['class'] = 'vacancy';

                    $data['validationErrors'] = validation_errors();
                    $imageOk = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                    $data['imgErrors'] = $imageOk['error'];
                    $content = 'dashboard/vacancy/error';
                }
            } else {
                // Passing Variables
                $data['title'] = 'Give a Day - Error';
                $data['class'] = 'vacancy';

                $data['validationErrors'] = validation_errors();
                //$imageOk = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                //$data['imgErrors'] = $imageOk['error'];
                $content = 'dashboard/vacancy/error';
            }

            // Template declaration
            $partials = array('head' => '_master/header/head', 'navigation' => '_master/header/navigation_dashboard', 'content' => $content, 'footer' => '_master/footer/footer');
            $this->template->load('_master/master', $partials, $data);
        } else {
            //User does not have correct permissions --> Go to 404
            redirect(site_url( 'error/my404', $redirect_protocol));
        }
    } else {
        //User is anonymous -> go to login page (and remember the current URL for redirecting again after log in)
        $this->session->set_flashdata('referred_from', uri_string());
        redirect(site_url( 'login?redirect=user', $redirect_protocol));
    }
}
```

Note that when I upload an image of 19 MB, for some reason I end up in the else clause all the way at the bottom and I get a page showing all the validation errors saying "Wat heb je te bieden is verplicht.", "naam is verplicht", ... and all of them literally. 
All data is filled in correctly, and when i perform the exact same steps, but take an image which is less than 3MB, it works perfect.

So 0-3MB - works perfect.
3-10MB - gives perfect error
and >10 MB - gives all validation errors.

Comment: what CI and PHP version are you using?

Comment: That's a lot of code to sift through. You ought to reduce the code you're showing us down to what is relevant to the problem.

Comment: ^ Please narrow down the code to only what's relevant. Perhaps in doing so you may also find the problem by process of elimination. When this much code is involved its nearly impossible for us to replicate, and therefore fix the issue unless the error is typographical in nature.

Comment: Unrelated: `$config['quality'] = 60;` is not an option in the upload library. If you want to resize and change the quality it is recommended to use image_lib, if you want to just change the quality image_lib won't work for that (had it in another question) use something like verot upload for that.

Comment: To reduce image size, I prefer client side image manipulation using html5  canvas https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API over the Php image libraries (used by CI). At least my server is not paying for extra-large image uploads. Back to the OP: in my opinion server doesn't handle larger images and throws a 500, and therefore you experience `"I end up in the else clause all the way at the bottom "`

Comment: @Vickel that's strange behavior because, as I understood it, a 500 completely stops script execution. The upload part serving 500 (which is somewhere in the middle) would result in the next lines not getting reached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find this useful, this is a helper I've created for form uploads to determine the maximum size for uploads based on `post_max_size` and `upload_max_size`

Usage:

`$config['max_size'] = convert_bytes_to_type(file_upload_max_size(), 'KB');`

Helper:

```
/**
 * Gets max upload size from post_max_size and upload_max_filesize
 * Returns whichever is smaller
 *
 * @return int
 */
function file_upload_max_size() {
    $max_size = convert_to_bytes(ini_get('post_max_size'));
    $upload_max = convert_to_bytes(ini_get('upload_max_filesize'));
    if ($upload_max > 0 && $upload_max < $max_size) {
        $max_size = $upload_max;
    }
    return $max_size;
}

/**
 * Converts KB (K) through GB (G) to bytes
 *
 * @param string $from
 * @return int bytes
 */
function convert_to_bytes($from) {
    $number = filter_var($from, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    if (empty($number)) {
        return 0;
    }
    $type = strtoupper(str_replace($number, '', $from));
    switch ($type) {
        case "KB":
        case "K":
            $number = $number * 1024;
            break;
        case "MB":
        case "M":
            $number = $number * pow(1024, 2);
            break;
        case "GB":
        case "G":
            $number = $number * pow(1024, 3);
            break;
        default:
            return 0;
    }
    return fix_integer_overflow($number);
}

/**
 * Converts bytes to KB (K) through GB (G)
 *
 * @param int $bytes
 * @param string $type Type to convert to
 *                     KB (K) through GB (G)
 * @return int bytes
 */
function convert_bytes_to_type($bytes, $type = 'MB') {
    $number = filter_var($bytes, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    if (empty($number)) {
        return 0;
    }
    $type = strtoupper($type);
    switch ($type) {
        case "KB":
        case "K":
            $divisor = 1024;
            break;
        case "MB":
        case "M":
            $divisor = pow(1024, 2);
            break;
        case "GB":
        case "G":
            $divisor = pow(1024, 3);
            break;
        default:
            return 0;
    }
    return $bytes / $divisor;
}

/**
 * Converts bytes into human readable form
 *
 * @param string || File
 * @param int precision round precision
 * @return int rounded bytes in units
 */
function human_readable_bytes($bytes, $precision = 2) {
    $CI = & get_instance();
    $CI->lang->load('number');
    if (is_file($bytes)) {
        $bytes = fix_integer_overflow(filesize($bytes));
    }
    $units = array(
        $CI->lang->line('bytes'),
        $CI->lang->line('kilobyte_abbr'),
        $CI->lang->line('megabyte_abbr'),
        $CI->lang->line('gigabyte_abbr'),
        $CI->lang->line('terabyte_abbr')
    );
    $bytes = max($bytes, 0);
    $pow = floor(($bytes ? log($bytes) : 0) / log(1024));
    $pow = min($pow, count($units) - 1);
    $bytes /= pow(1024, $pow);
    return round($bytes, $precision) . ' ' . $units[$pow];
}

/**
 * Fixes integer overflow
 *
 * @param int $size
 * @return int
 */
function fix_integer_overflow($size) {
    if ($size < 0) {
        $size += 2.0 * (PHP_INT_MAX + 1);
    }
    return $size;
}
```

https://pastebin.com/2zDJ90Qr

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that post_max_size in php.ini was set to 8MB, this caused the $_POST variable to become NULL... Setting an if case to check if $_POST is not null solved the issue! Thanks